# How can I use opencv features and connect it to game engine?

Tags: opencv, unity-game-engine, unreal-engine4

I'm taking software engineering class.
I had to choose a project to work on, so I decided to make a hand gesture control system for games.
I learned opencv before, started trying out Unity and Unreal Engine, so I wanted to apply my knowledge for both.
So my question is, how can I pass output variables from opencv as inputs to the game engine?
I have absolutely no clue where to start from.

Comment: This is a big question, and SO is usually more for specific problems with code. Seeing as there's no code here, you might be better off elsewhere. In any case, I suggest you breakdown the problem into pieces. You haven't mentioned at what step of using UE4 you're at, but once you have a C++ project you'll need to add the OpenCV library to it. From there, it's like regular C++, and you could use the OpenCV API in a Tick().

Comment: Thx for the comment. I did some research and found out that this was a really dumb question; I didn't even know opencv was a library and started asking without googling it myself. But thx anyways.